# is there a winapi call that can set colors in a console like 'color xx' command?

Tags: c++, winapi, colors, console

I know I can do `system("color 1E")` for example, but I am curious if there is an api call that can do just that, since these are faster and I need to color all console just like `color` does. Only api call I know is `SetConsoleTextAttribute()` but this is coloring only the text that is written after it is used.

Comment: You can use that, set the cursor to the beginning, reprint what was there and fill the rest of the screen with spaces, and set the cursor back to the original position. I think there is something for Vista+ though.

Comment: Ah, I found what I remembered for Vista and up: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686039%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. Here's a member of the struct: `ColorTable

    An array of COLORREF values that describe the console's color settings.
`. I haven't used it, but it seems promising.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I debugged cmd.exe (on Windows 7) and here is what the "color" command does:

```
HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csBufferInfo;
GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsole, &csBufferInfo);
DWORD dwLength = csBufferInfo.dwSize.X * csBufferInfo.dwSize.Y;
COORD dwOrigin = { 0 };
DWORD dwWritten = 0;
FillConsoleOutputAttribute(hConsole, wAttribute, dwLength, dwOrigin, &dwWritten);
SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, wAttribute);
```

where `wAttribute` holds your desired colors.

Answer (score 2):

[WriteConsoleOutputAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687407%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) can be used to write character attributes to consecutive cells in the screen buffer. This will change the attributes for each cell in the screen buffer without modifying existing text.

```
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO sb;
        HANDLE h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        WORD attr = BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_GREEN | BACKGROUND_BLUE;
        COORD c = {0};
        int row, col;
        GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(h, &sb);

        for(row = 0; row < sb.dwSize.Y; row++)
        {
                c.Y = row;
                for(col = 0; col < sb.dwSize.X; col++)
                {
                        c.X = col;
                        WriteConsoleOutputAttribute(h, &attr, 1, c, NULL);
                }
        }
}
```

Note you will need to also use `SetConsoleTextAttribute()` as new text written will still be using the old attributes.

Answer (score -1):

I compiled this answer from multiple sources. The basic idea is given in

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/5830/.

However, they use system("cls").

S, I tried replacing system("cls") with the technique mentioned here. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/99261

And the result was what you expect.

It doesn't look pretty. But, this is one answer, I think.
Best of luck.